# (Tomcat 8). Error 401 when using URL with server name, but OK if using IP address

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-401, spnego

I've the following error on Tomcat 8.
I wrote a Tomcat application that relies on SPNEGO.
When I connect to the application using the IP adress :
http://123.11.22.33:8080/ABC/de
it works (I can connect to the application).

But if I try to connect to the same application using the server name :
http://ServerName:8080/ABC/de
I've got an 401 error.

When I try to reach http://ServerName:8080/ABC works (without the application name), it works.
Also, I have access to the Tomcat main page (http://ServerName:8080).
So, I don't think it's a DNS problem.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried doing the first step here:
http://spnego.sourceforge.net/spnego_tomcat.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Problems are that :
 - I'm using NTLM instead of Kerberos
 - I'm running Tomcat as a standalone soft, not as a Service.
And the page talks about Kerberos and Tomcat as Service...

Comment: I would still try changing the name and domain of the computer if you didn't do that already (assuming you are using Windows).